# Equivalent of Hyperledger Composer CTO model file in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

For my Hyperledger Business Network, have defined all my network objects (Enums, Assets, Participants, Transactions, Events etc) in a Composer CTO Model file. I also use the Concept, Abstract and Relationship (-->) features as well in the cto file.

Is there an equivalent of CTO model file in the new development model in HL 1.4 without Composer. If not what's the best way to achieve the same as a model CTO file?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, There is no alternative the same as the CTO file. **Hyperledger Composer** follows a Modeling language for the asset, participants creation.

**Hyperledger Fabric** supports Smart Contact development in general-purpose programming languages, such as JavaScript, Java, Go, and Node.js.

If you are a beginner in Hypelredger fabric development then you have first cleared the concept of the orderer, peer, CA, and organization concept. And then first you have to start I**BM Blockchain Platform VS Code extension** for fabric. It will provide a local fabric environment to create, test and deploy a fabric smart contract. Also generate 1 peer, 1 orderer, 1 CA service under VS code environment.

Here is a [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain?topic=blockchain-develop-vscode) to start development with VS code extension. So using VS Code extension you can create a transaction for asset and participate creation.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info Isha. I had already come across the IBM extension and various examples in the fabric-samples suite and creation of main objects ( assets) via Transactions.

I was more wondering on best ( and fast/less code) way to implement other CTO features like Concept, Abstract and Relationship (-->). But looks like there isn’t.

Comment: You could use typescript or java to define your model which will give you a replacement for things like Concept, Abstract but you would need to come up with your own mechanism for Relationship